# Find all files in a directory on another server in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, authorization, os.walk

I'd like to be able to list all files found in a directory tree on a server that requires authorization for access.  If I were trying to list files within a local directory tree, I would use the os.walk functionality (quite simple, I like that); however, when I'm trying to search a secure server, I'm lost.  I know the credentials to log onto that server, but I'm not sure of the steps needed to log in and retrieve the information above (I'm new to python).  Can anyone provide examples?  Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information here. How are you accessing said server? Do you have shell access? What machine should process the files listed (locally or remotely)? What are you going to do with the files you listed (again, do you need local or remote access to the results).

Comment: Which operating system do you use? What Kind of server is it? A Website, A windows share, FTP, ssh. There are so many kinds of servers. There are many different ways for many different servers.